# Remove Cortana from Taskbar but don't disable Cortana

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I don't like the large Cortana widget on the W10 taskbar, not only does it take up loads of space but sometimes I press it accidentally (or do something which activates it without meaning to).

However I wouldn't mind having Cortana, available through a keyboard shortcut instead of the widget. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click anywhere on the **taskbar**.

Click **Cortana** and select **Hidden**.

**Note:**
IF you want you can select show the cortana Icon and you can access her that way.

These would be the best options for you I believe.